# Inequality in the Sobolev space $H^1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I've found the following inequality
$$\int_{B_r}\vert u\vert^q\leq C \bigg(\int_{B_r}\vert\nabla u\vert^2\bigg)^{a}\bigg(\int_{B_r}\vert u\vert ^2\bigg)^{\frac{q}{2}-a}+\frac{c}{r^{2a}}\bigg(\int_{B_r}\vert u\vert ^2\bigg) ^{\frac{q}{2}}$$
for $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$,$a=\frac{3}{4}(q-2)$ and $q\in [2,6]$.
Some hints to prove it?
I've started using interpolation and Sobolev's inequality
$$\int_{B_r}\vert u\vert^q\leq \Vert u\Vert_{L^2}^{q(1-\theta)}\Vert u\Vert_{L^6}^{q \theta}\leq C \Vert u\Vert_{L^2}^{q(1-\theta)}\Vert u\Vert_{H^1}^{q\theta}$$
with $\theta=\frac{3}{2}\frac{q-2}{q}$. How can I go on?

Comment: Where or how did you find it?

Comment: In a paper about Navier-Stokes equation.

Comment: Prove it on a sphere of radius 1 and then rescale

Answer (score 3):

Hint. For every $r>0$, and $q\le 6$,
$$
W^{1,2}(B_r)\subset L^6(B_r)\subset L^q(B_r),
$$
due to [Sobolev Imbedding Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality).

In particular, there is a $c>0$, such that
$$
\|u\|_{L^q(B_r)}^2 \le c_1 \big(\|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2(B_r)}+\|u\|^2_{L^2(B_r)}\big),
$$
for all $u\in W^{1,2}(B_r)$.